# $event not support in IOS, it not work in Iphone devices - Angular2

Tags: jquery

Use img tag in html of angular 2

```html
<img (load)="show($event)">
```

And in TS file call a

```js
function show(element) {element.path['0'].className = 'portrait-w-100';}
```

I am trying to add class using this function but it not support in IOS , I checked in iphone but not works. Use img tag in html of angular 2

```html
<img (load)="show($event)">
```

And in TS file call a

```js
function show(element) { element.path['0'].className = 'portrait-w-100'; }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to make it more readable.

Comment: Console log and see if the element is being recognized